# How to filter multiple JSON Data with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

My JSON file

```
{
records: [
{
Name: "Alfreds Futterkiste",
City: "Berlin",
Country: "Germany"
},
{
Name: "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
City: "México D.F.",
Country: "Mexico"
},
{
Name: "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
City: "México D.F.",
Country: "Mexico"
},
{
Name: "Around the Horn",
City: "London",
Country: "UK"
}
]
}
```

How can I filter only name of user with Country: "Mexico" or "Germany" with AngularJS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about performance you should better no use `$filter` provider. Instead you should go for a custom code.

You should better maintain a list of filtered records.

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <label ng-repeat="country in app.availableCountries track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.selected" ng-click="app.filterByCountries()"> {{country.name}}
  </label>

  <h2>Filtered Records</h2>

  <div ng-repeat="record in app.filteredRecords">
    {{record | json}}
  </div>

</div>
```

And perform filtering functionality in your controller.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller("AppController", function() {

  this.records = [{
    Name: "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    City: "Berlin",
    Country: "Germany"
  }, {
    Name: "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
    City: "México D.F.",
    Country: "Mexico"
  }, {
    Name: "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
    City: "México D.F.",
    Country: "Mexico"
  }, {
    Name: "Around the Horn",
    City: "London",
    Country: "UK"
  }];

  this.filteredRecords = [];

  this.availableCountries = _.uniq(this.records.map(record => record.Country)).map(country => {
    return {
      name: country
    }
  });

  this.filterByCountries = () => {
    const lowerCaseCountries = this.availableCountries.filter(country => country.selected).map(country => country.name.toLowerCase());

    if (!lowerCaseCountries.length) {
      this.filteredRecords = angular.copy(this.records);
      return;
    }

    this.filteredRecords = angular.copy(this.records.filter(record => lowerCaseCountries.includes(record.Country.toLowerCase())));
  }

  this.filterByCountries();

})
```

Here's a [working fiddle demonstrating your case](https://jsfiddle.net/d8j0ajk9/1/). Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.data = records: [
{
Name: "Alfreds Futterkiste",
City: "Berlin",
Country: "Germany"
},
{
Name: "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
City: "México D.F.",
Country: "Mexico"
},
{
Name: "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
City: "México D.F.",
Country: "Mexico"
},
{
Name: "Around the Horn",
City: "London",
Country: "UK"
}
];

$scope.filteredData = $scope.data.filter(function(d) {
return d.Country === 'Mexico' || d.Country === 'Germany'
});

});
```

Comment: Please do upvote if u found the solution. Thank You.